# loadUi() loads everything but no Images in PyQt

Tags: qt, pyqt

I have created my .ui file in Qt Designers I am then using loadUI() to load it into my app below.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class Life2Coding(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Life2Coding, self).__init__()
        loadUi('new.ui', self)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget=Life2Coding()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However when I go to run this the images will not show up, which is odd as in the Qt designer when I click preview the images actually show up.

Also on a side note if its helpful I am using a xz.prc file for a prefix / path which is how the Qt designer is writing the code linking to the images.

Please could you suggest ways in which I might get the images from new.ui show in my app? Also all widgets work including labels its just the images that do not show up when I run this.

Thanks
Carl

**.ui file in its native format**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
<class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
  <rect>
<x>0</x>
<y>0</y>
<width>1343</width>
<height>965</height>
</rect>
</property>
<property name="windowTitle">
<string>Dialog</string>
</property>
<widget class="QLabel" name="label">
<property name="geometry">
  <rect>
 <x>730</x>
 <y>740</y>
 <width>521</width>
 <height>171</height>
</rect>
</property>
<property name="frameShape">
    <enum>QFrame::Box</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string/>
    </property>
   <property name="pixmap">
    <pixmap resource="xz.qrc">:/newPrefix/me.jpg</pixmap>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>60</x>
     <y>530</y>
     <width>651</width>
     <height>271</height>
     </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="pixmap">
    <pixmap resource="xz.qrc">:/newPrefix/logo.png</pixmap>
   </property>
 </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>930</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>331</width>
     <height>301</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">image: url(:/newPrefix/logo.png);</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>TextLabel</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>280</x>
     <y>180</y>
     <width>68</width>
    <height>19</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>TextLabel</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="xz.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**xz.prc**

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="newPrefix">
    <file>logo.png</file>
    <file>me.jpg</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**xz_rc.py**
This is after it has been converted from xz.prc

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore

qt_resource_data = b

 qt_version = QtCore.qVersion().split('.')
    if qt_version < ['5', '8', '0']:
        rcc_version = 1
        qt_resource_struct = qt_resource_struct_v1
    else:
        rcc_version = 2
        qt_resource_struct = qt_resource_struct_v2

    def qInitResources():
        QtCore.qRegisterResourceData(rcc_version, qt_resource_struct, qt_resource_name, qt_resource_data)

    def qCleanupResources():
        QtCore.qUnregisterResourceData(rcc_version, qt_resource_struct, qt_resource_name, qt_resource_data)

    qInitResources()
```

Comment: you could provide the .ui

Comment: do not convert it to .py, just show the .ui, the .ui is an .xml so you should be able to open it with any decent editor :)

Comment: ohh sorry I just removed the .py converted part leaving just the native .ui now. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried converting the .qrc to .py? `pyrcc5 xz.qrc -o xz_rc.py`

Comment: I just gave it a try i created the .py I ran the app but it still did not show images would I need to change anything else to get it to use the xz_rc.py?

Comment: share the xz.qrc file to be able to test it and see where the problem is.

Comment: I just edited my question to contain the code of xz.py is this what you mean by share? Sorry still fairly new to stackoverflow.

Comment: `xz.prc` or `xz.qrc`?

Comment: Sorry I meant .qrc but ill also add what it looks like after converting to .py also

Comment: Its working I just needed to import xz_rc.py Thank you so much! How do I accept this as the answer if its just a comment?

Comment: I invite you to post an answer to you and mark it as correct. Askers can also post an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .qrc file maybe what Qt designer uses to connect to images however when I am loading the .ui file into my .py app it is having trouble using the .qrc file so instead I need to create a .py version of .qrc.

Go to the directory that .qrc is located in using command prompt and write in this command. Note xz is just what I called it yours may be called thing else.

```
pyrcc5 xz.qrc -o xz_rc.py
```

Then import this into your .py app no need to add .py on the end as we are importing this as a module.

```
import xz.rc
```

Now your .py app shall display images thanks to having access to a format it can now understand.